# RxJS / Angular 2 / @ngrx/store /effects how to combine actions

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm using Angular2 with @ngrx/store & effects... I have an authenticate effect like this

```
@Effect() authenticate$ = this.updates$
  .whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST)
  .switchMap(update => this.api.post('/authenticate', update.action.payload)
  // somehow use data in the original `update` to work out if we need to
  // store the users credentials after successful api auth call
    .map((res:any) => this.authActions.authenticateSuccess(res.json()))
    .catch((err:any) => Observable.of(this.authActions.authenticateError(err)))
)
```

Within the `update.action.payload` object is a `rememberMe` flag. So... if set to `true` i need to store the credentials in a `LocalStorage` service *AFTER* the api request has returned successfully... but obviously not if there is an error.

How can this be achieved as inside the `switchMap` operator we only have access to the result of the api post call?

---

**WORKING CODE FROM ANSWER BELOW**

```
@Effect() authenticate$ = this.updates$
.whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST)
.switchMap(update => this.api.post('/authenticate', update.action.payload)
  .map((res:any) => {
    return {
      res: res,
      update: update
    };
  })
  .do((result:any) => {
    if(result.update.action.payload.remember) {
      this.authService.setAuth(result.res.json());
    }
  })
  .map((result:any) => this.authActions.authenticateSuccess(result.res.json()))
  .catch((err:any) => Observable.of(this.authActions.authenticateError(err)))
);
```

Comment: I can think of one or two ways to do this, but they're going to be hacky. The cleanest way (IMHO) is going to be to have the `rememberMe` field come back in the API response - is that possible for you?

Comment: That'd definitely be the cleanest but unfortunately I don't have control of what backend returns..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to `map` the `post` observable to include `update`:

```
@Effect() authenticate$ = this.updates$
  .whenAction(AuthActions.AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST)
  .switchMap(update => this.api.post('/authenticate', update.action.payload).map((res:any) => {
    return {
      res: res,
      update: update
    };
  }))
  .do((result:any) => { ... whatever it is you need to do with result.update ... })
  .map((result:any) => this.authActions.authenticateSuccess(result.res.json()))
  .catch((err:any) => Observable.of(this.authActions.authenticateError(err)))
)
```

Comment: Thanks @cartant! This is what I was trying to do! (Just need to remove extra bracket from end of .switchMap)

Comment: This doesn't work though - the argument to `switchMap()` needs to return an Observable, which is not the case here.

Comment: Ah, okay I didn't look closely enough. You're right, good answer: +1. For the record though, you can replace `((res:any)=>{return {res: res, update:update}})` by `((res:any)=>({res: res, update:update}))`. Note that the object literal is surrounded by parentheses :-)